# Unity - resizing particles dont mantain collisions properly

Tags: unity

I am trying to make particles for blood on death. This is what I got so far:

[image]

Which looks fine and all. But now I also wanted to make the blood particles turn smaller over their lifetime, so I checked "Size over lifetime" and this is what happens now:

[image]

See the problem? As they shrink, they seem to float a little, giving some space between the floor they are laying on. This behaviour is not really desired.

How could I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Reduce the radius scale value as needed. Tweak how near you want the particles with the value.

[image]

You can change `particleSystem.collision.radiusScale` in runtime to avoid sinking.

Comment: While this solves the problem of the floating particles, as they shrink, it introduces a new problem. Now there are "sinking" particles before they start shrinking...